# Mapping nested array data with React-Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, javascript-objects

So I have this JSON that I received and the format looks like this:

```
let json = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to map the content of the "data" array but I can't figure out how to do it, here's what I tried

```
let dataObj = json.data[0];
let dataArray = Object.keys(dataObj).map(key => {
  let obj = dataObj[key];
  obj.keyName = key;
  return obj;
});
```

Comment: What would be the output of what you want?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: I want the output to be an array of objects

Comment: So you just want a new array of objects that contains what exactly? Your current code just grabs the first object and creates an array of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
const data = json.data.map(obj => obj)
```

or if we assume that data key is an array in json obj you can do this using object destructuring.

```
const {data} = json
```